# How can I login into a domain user account or login as other user in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, login, lightdm, user-management, adduser

I do have a kubuntu box connected to our Windows AD DC, and now i want to login one domain user in my AD to my kubuntu box but I cannot find a way to log as other user in the login screen. I tried to edit the '40-lightdm-kde-greeter.conf' and put a "greeter-show-manual-login=true" in it but still my login option is still the same. Hope you can help me. Thanks!